# Any API to read property file without Spring in annotation way

Tags: java, spring, reflection, properties, annotations

I am **not** using Spring in my application. Is there any API which can load property file into java pojo based on annotation. 
I am aware of loading properties file using either InputStream Or with Spring's PropertyPlaceHolder.
Is there any API using which I can populate my pojo like

```
@Value("{foo.somevar}")
private String someVariable;
```

I was unable to find any solution **WITHOUT** using spring.

Comment: A `.properties` file? Have you tried `ResourceBundle`? It won't work as you are trying, though.

Comment: You can write your own. Using reflection API.

Comment: @MdFaraz Yes that is what I am doing now, but if there is a API well proven, its worth usage as that will be better tested with features.

Comment: If spring does what you want, and you don't want to write your own, why *not* use spring?

Comment: @azurefrog as I use spring, that means whole DI and other core framework in my JVM. And I don't require any Spring specific features

Comment: You can check Google guice. But there would be learning curve better write your own. Believe me it won't be big effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I come up with a quick hack to bind properties as follows.

**Note: It is not optimized, not error-handled. Just showing one possibility.**

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Bind
{
    String value();
}
```

I have tested it some basic params and is working.

```
class App
{
    @Bind("msg10")
    private String msg1;
    @Bind("msg11")
    private String msg2;

    //setters & getters
}

public class PropertyBinder 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, IllegalAccessException 
    {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        InputStream stream = PropertyBinder.class.getResourceAsStream("/app.properties");
        props.load(stream);
        System.out.println(props);
        App app = new App();
        bindProperties(props, app);

        System.out.println("Msg1="+app.getMsg1());
        System.out.println("Msg2="+app.getMsg2());

    }

    static void bindProperties(Properties props, Object object) throws IllegalAccessException 
    {
        for(Field field  : object.getClass().getDeclaredFields())
        {
            if (field.isAnnotationPresent(Bind.class))
            {
                Bind bind = field.getAnnotation(Bind.class);
                String value = bind.value();
                String propValue = props.getProperty(value);
                System.out.println(field.getName()+":"+value+":"+propValue);
                field.setAccessible(true);
                field.set(object, propValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Create `app.properties` in root classpath.

```
msg10=message1
msg11=message2
```